# I forgot username,so how recover username please tell me

Tags: boot, networking

System is showing that something went wrong contact a system administrator.then I find and get this,at first press- Alt+fn+ctrl+f3,after this I give my username and password but can't login.I am sure about password but not sure about username.so how recover username please tell me.....

Comment: If it was me; I'd do the same thing I'd do with a windows system where I'd forgotten details.. Boot *live* media and explore the disk yourself, unless your system was installed with encryption, you'll be able to read most of what is there (*regardless of OS, be it windows, mac os, or a Ubuntu system*).   You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; thus we can only be *generic* in responses anyway; for best results it's best if you're specific about your OS & release.